# how to put tab fragment inside navigation drawer fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

This is my `MainActivity.java`. I have an error when I called a tabbed fragment inside it. the error is in the line

```
fragment = new FriendsFragment();
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;  import info.androidhive.materialdesign.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.action_search){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FriendsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MessagesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
}
```

my `friendsfragment` is extended with `appcompatactivity`. could you help me how to clear the error. the `friendsfragment`.java is also attached here

**FriendsFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import info.androidhive.materialdesign.R;
import info.androidhive.materialdesign.adapter.PagerAdapter;

public class FriendsFragment extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_friends);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}  
}
```

**The error is**

```
Error:(85, 28) error: incompatible types: FriendsFragment cannot be converted to Fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `FriendsFragment` cannot be converted to fragment and that is correct because it is not a fragment, it is an activity, instead of extending from `AppCompatActivity` it should extend from `Fragment` or `FragmentActivity`.

This should make it work, happy coding.

Comment: the error got less when i changed it into "FragmentActivity". bt still there is an error as " Cannot resolve method 'getSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)' "

Answer (score 0):

Your FriendsFragement is extending AppCompatActivity...

You have to change

```
public class FriendsFragment extends AppCompatActivity {
```

to

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {
```

and make other changes is your FriendsFragment accordingly...

**You cant cast Activity to Fragment....